# RedirectToAction and HTML.ActionLink pages in browser history

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4

I am using the following code in global.asax, in MVC 4, to restrict pages from being in browser history and it works as expected:

```
protected void Application_BeginRequest()
    {
        Response.Cache.SetCacheability(HttpCacheability.NoCache);
        Response.Cache.SetAllowResponseInBrowserHistory(false);
        Response.Cache.SetExpires(DateTime.UtcNow.AddHours(-1));
        Response.Cache.SetNoStore();
    }
```

However, pages that are loaded via RedirectToAction and @Html.ActionLink are still accessible via the browser history. For example, my login code in the controller validates the user and if valid redirects to an action called Cycles which returns a view (Constants.cyclesActionName="Cycles"):

```
        [Authorize]
    public ActionResult SubmitLogin(LoginViewModel model)
    {
        Login userLogin = new Login();

        bool loginSuccessful = userLogin.LoginUser(Constants.domainName, model.UserName, model.Password);

        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(model.Password) || (string.IsNullOrEmpty(model.UserName)))
        {
            return RedirectToAction(Constants.loginActionName);
        }

        if (loginSuccessful)
        {
            return RedirectToAction(Constants.cyclesActionName);
        }
        else
        {
            ViewData[Constants.messageBoxIndex] = Constants.loginFailureString;
            return View(Constants.loginActionName, model);
        }
    }
```

Here is the Cycles action:

```
        [Authorize]
    public ActionResult Cycles()
    {
        SortOrder initSortOrder = new SortOrder();
        System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Session[Constants.sortOrderSessionName] = initSortOrder;

        List<Cycle> Cycles = new FileMethods().GetCycles(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings[Constants.cycleFileLocationFromWebConfig]);
        CycleViewModel model = new CycleViewModel();
        model.Cycles = Cycles.OrderByDescending(x => x.StartDate).ToList();

        System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Session[Constants.cycleSessionName] = Cycles;

        return View(Constants.cyclesActionName, model);
    }
```

And here is the code in my view:

```
            @Html.ActionLink("Return to Cycle List", "Cycles", "NSQIP")
```

I've seen plenty of posts about hiding browser history in general but none that address this issue with RedirectToAction or Html.ActionLink.

My question is, how can I restrict those views from the browsing history as well?

Thanks very much!!!

Comment: What do you mean with Browser History? This is the one used in Browser's Back button? Or the autocomplete feature in the URL textbox?

Comment: I'm referring to what's listed in the "History" (Ctrl+H in IE). I didn't realize it was different from what's in the back button etc.